# Latin language dependency parser

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I know about StanfordNLP parser but it does not cater for the Latin language. Any idea for dependency parsers for Latin pls?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately at this time we do not have any models for Latin that we distribute.  But you can just train your own

There are instructions for training your own model here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/depparse.html

That site also has a link to where Latin training data can be found.